# Handle logins Zend Auth & ACL on Custom Php Site

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-form, acl

I have a custom php site and I want to add the ability of ACL and logins. Would it be possible to handle all these with zend functions but without rebulding the whole site on zend framework?
Thank you!

Comment: More of a follow up to the answer - check out this post: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1466252/zend-framework-1-9-how-to-use-autoloading-without-mvc][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1466252/zend-framework-1-9-how-to-use-autoloading-without-mvc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Yes**,

This is the beauty of zend framework you can use how much you want to use. For your requirement just include the zend loader in your index.php and some more code of bootstraping thats it and now you can use any component of ZEND.

Comment: thank you very much! are there any examples that i could check?

Comment: are there any code examples that do not refer to the full use of the framework?